# Bolzano's theorem for $x^5-x^2+3 = 2019$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Prove rigorously using the definition of limits that there exists an $x \in \mathbb{R}$, such that $$x^5-x^2+3 = 2019.$$

My suggestion for this went as follows:

Let $f(x) = x^5-x^2+3$.

Now since 
$$x^5-x^2+3 \geqslant x^5-x^2 = x^2(x^3-1) \geqslant x^2 \geqslant x$$

therefore by definition we can choose $N = M$ and we get that $$f(x) \geqslant x \geqslant N = M, \text{when } x> N$$

so  $f(x) \to \infty$, when $x\to \infty.$

From the limit definition we can say $\forall M$ $\exists N >0$ such that, when $x >N$ we have that $f(x) >M.$

Now let $M=2020$. We have that $f(x) > 2020$ and now by Bolzano's theorem $\exists x_0 \in[0, 2020]$ such that $f(x_0) = 2019.$

Any comments on this? I would gladly hear if this is not rigorous enough.

Comment: Careful: $x^2(x^3-1)\geq x^2$ doesn’t hold for every real number $x$

Comment: Nor does $x^2≥x$.

Comment: $f(4)=1011\lt 2019\lt f(5)=3103$. What do you want?

Comment: It is overkill and not entirely right.  If you want to say $f(x) > x^2(x^3-1) > x^2 > x$ this is only true if $x>2^\frac 13.$  Furthermore, you have not shown that there exists an $x$ such that $f(x) < 2018.$  Nor have you explained why having find values where $f(x)$ is greater than $2018$ and less than $2018$ means that there is a place where $f(x) = 2018$

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$ f(x)=x^5-x^2-2016. $$
Obviously $f(0)=-2016<0$. Let $M=\sqrt{2016}$. Clearly $M>2$ and hence
$$ f(M)=M^2(M^3-1)-2016>M^2-2016=0. $$
So $f(0)f(M)<0$. Since $f(x)$ is continuous in $[0,M]$, by Bolzano's theorem, there exits $x\in(0,M)$ such that $f(x)=0$ or
$$ x^5-x^2+3=2019. $$